# Difference between "findViewById" and "new View(content)"

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a 3x4 grid of buttons using the following code:

```
public class Grid extends AppCompatActivity {

    LinearLayout myLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_grid);
        myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_grid);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
            LayoutParams rowParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            row.setLayoutParams(rowParams);

            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                final Button btn = new Button(this);
                LayoutParams btnParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                btn.setLayoutParams(btnParams);
                btn.setText(" " + (j + 1 + (i * 4)));
                btn.setId(j + 1 + (i * 4));
                row.addView(btn);
            }
            myLayout.addView(row);
        }
    setContentView(myLayout);;
}
```

}

This code works perfectly fine and creates the grid as I want it, however if I change the line

```
myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_grid);
```

to

```
myLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
```

Then only the first row of the grid is produced, not the 2nd and 3rd. I want to know why this is happening?

Whether the line

```
setContentView(R.id.content_grid);
```

is there or not does not seem make a difference in the second case.

In addition my content_grid.xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content_grid"
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: how does your layout content_grid look like?

Comment: Just edited the question to add that.

Comment: are you adding layoutparameter for myLayout?

Comment: Yes but that doesn't help either. If I use LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT), then the buttons are produced are created in a single row and start going off screen. Any other combination of "MATCH_PARENT" and "WRAP_CONTENT" results in the same single row of buttons.

Comment: Did you set the orientation? Because that seems to be the problem

Comment: Yes that was exactly it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

By default `LinearLayout`  set orientation horizontal. Try set orientation vertical to `myLayout` by one `LayoutParams`.